# Can I copy a PGP revocation to another server?

Tags: key-management, gnupg, pgp

I have a few PGP keys from long ago that I no longer use. I thought I had revoked them everywhere I had uploaded them but I just noticed I missed one keyserver. Unfortunately, I only have access to the revocation certificate for one of them.

Is there a way to transfer the revocation from another keyserver to the one I missed? I had assumed that if I just downloaded the revoked public key from some other server and uploaded it to the out-of-date server, it would be revoked there too (after all, when you fetch a revoked certificate into your keyring, your keyring knows it's revoked). But that does not seem to be working.

**Edit:**

Well, I feel silly. Turns out they *were* revoked all along, and the web interface for this keyserver simply doesn't show revocation status (surprisingly). But if the keys are actually fetched from the server, they are indeed revoked.

However, I suppose there is still a useful question here for future readers: Would the method I described above work?

Answer (score 0):

You mean a revocation-certificate, right?
The public-key remains the same, but you can calculate a 'message' stating your key is no longer in use and people can check this signed message with your public-key.
This *is* a certificate-revocation and it's made with your private key and then - just published.

Maybe you can grab your revocation-cert from somewhere and re-publish it again?

Comment: Maybe. I know for many keyservers, the revocation certificate must be applied to the public key, rather than uploading the revocation certificate directly, and I was hoping that the downloaded key would still have the revocation signature attached to it, as if I had just applied the revocation certificate.

Comment: Well - have you tried uploading it to the keyserver?
Like: loading it into kleopatra and sending it ?

Comment: Yes. (Well, with gpg, not kleopatra.)